# Need to share a string across threads (Boost)

Tags: c++

Good day,

I'm trying to figure out the syntax of a shared pointer for a string. Via boost. For example, I have:

boost::shared_ptr name

declared. I'd like to know what the syntax might be to set a text to it, and read text from this. I think setting text would be:

name.reset("Your text")

But I'm not sure about reading the text and displaying it etc.

Comment: Why don't you read documentation? Also why use boots if c++11 have it's own shared pointers?

Comment: What does this have to do with threads?

Comment: When sharing across threads, you don't necessarily need a shared pointer, but you need some kind of protection like a mutex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a shared pointer so you can use 
`*name = "Your Text"`

```
std::cout << *name;
```

and so on